# Optical pumping & spin-changing collisions

Tags: atomic-physics, cold-atoms

[Optical pumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_pumping) is the method of 'pumping' all the electrons in the upmost $m_F$ state of the ground state, by shining $\sigma^+$ light such that eventually all the electrons end up in this state because there is no excited state that $\sigma^+$ light could excite them into.

'''Question''': While pumping is still occurring, there are electrons occupying all $m_F$ states, so couldn't there be spin-changing collisions that depopulate the population of the upmost optically-pumped $m_F$ state? Also, the excited states could decay into any other $m_F$ state (provided $\Delta m_F = 0, \pm1$).

What are the timescales of the spin-changing collisions and of atomic transitions between the ground and excited states? To know which one wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two factors that the rate of spin-changing collisions depends on:

1. Density, with a higher density leader to faster changing.
2. External bias magnetic field. Because of the second-order Zeeman transition, spin-changing collisions are generally only resonant near zero magnetic field. Off-resonant transitions are possible at low field but are suppressed as the field increases.

So, if you have a hot (and low-density) gas in a significant constant magnetic field, I suspect that this will generally be a negligible contribution to the spin dynamics during optical pumping. However, one would need to do a quantitative calculation for a given system to really know for sure.